# get total hard drive capacity excluding external devices

Tags: wmi

I am trying to get the total hard drive capacity using this WMI query : `SELECT Size FROM Win32_DiskDrive`

I tested it on a computer that had a flash drive connected and it showed `489 Gb` instead of `465 Gb`

Is there any filter I can use in the `WHERE` clause ? To select only local partitions ?

Comment: Check out the MediaType property. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-diskdrive)

Comment: @Porcupine911 Yes I saw it but it's a string. Does it change depending on Windows language or is it always english ?

Comment: I'm really not familiar with language dependence in system strings. Here are the enumerations for MediaType (in English, at least): [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ne-winioctl-media_type)